# Testing a websocket server with tsung

Tags: testing, socket.io, tsung

I start to use tsung to test my server with socket.io.

I downloaded the Github Zip, compiled and installed the latest "dev" including Websockets compatibility.

After browsing a lot of Google results and message in this mailing list, I couldn't find any answer to my issue. My problem is that I can't send/receive a message to my socket.io server. I'm able to connect to my socket with handshaking OK but nothing happens when I send the message. I tried to use bidir=true attribute but nothing change.

**In my tsung log, I've got this messages:**

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Sep-2013::08:08:00 ===

ts_client:(7:<0.93.0>) connect to port 80

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Sep-2013::08:08:00 ===

ts_client:(3:<0.93.0>) Data receive from socket in state think, stop

**In my socket log (server side), I've got this messages:**

- debug: client authorized for
- info: transport end (undefined)
- debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client b07GKwmOJPQVDwznBzN1
- debug: discarding transport

You can find my tsung.xml file here: http://pastebin.com/A60PpKrL

Please help,

Kind Regards,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

try the 1.5.1 version as its "stable" and your using a bleeding edge build.

Also, try and tcpdump and tell me what you see, maybe use pastebin to show me the request.